# Google plus api to get profile information using service account

Tags: google-app-engine

Forgive me if this question isn't the best, it's my first. I am writing an app using Google App Engine and I would like to get the first and given name of the logged in user. However, when I query the google plus api using the 'me' userId, I get my service account information back, rather than whoever is logged in. Here is a snippet:

```
import httplib2
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

credential_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(credential_scope)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))

profile = build('plus', 'v1', http=http)
mePerson = profile.people().get(userId='me').execute(http=http)
```

How can I ask it for the information of the person who is logged in? I was able to get my own information successfully by hard-coding my google+ user id. I have the user's gmail address at this point, but that's about it.

I have also tried using SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, but I got the following error:

"Unauthorized client or scope in request."

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I don't think this is possible. I ended up solving this on the front-end. This should be pretty close:

```
<style type="text/css">
#renderMe {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #4285f4;
  color: white;
  width: 190px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<div id="renderMe" class="customGPlusSignIn">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
</div>

<script>
var options = {
    'callback': "loginFinished",
    'client_id': "{{client_id}}",
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',
    'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init(options);
        attachSignin(document.getElementById('renderMe'));
    });
});

function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        loginFinished, 
        function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
    }
}

function loginFinished() {
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function()
    {
        gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp)
        {
            console.log("email: " + resp.email + " lastname: " +  resp.family_name + " firstname: " + resp.given_name);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```